# Measuring latency in a GStreamer pipeline

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I'm using a RTP pipeline to stream video from a camera over local network.
The pipeline is: camera > h264enc > RTP > UDP > receiver_and_display

How can I find out how the latency is composed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays GStreamer has really nice tracers mechanisms to measure latency as for the whole pipeline or for individual elements

This is how this can be done with `gst-launch`

```
env GST_DEBUG="GST_TRACER:7" \
    GST_TRACERS="latency(flags=element+pipeline)" \ 
    GST_DEBUG_FILE=./latency.log \
    gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

`./latency.log` will contain a lot of logs like this:

```
...
0:00:06.072184000 40898    0x11d816920 TRACE             GST_TRACER :0:: element-latency, element-id=(string)0x11e848210, element=(string)videotestsrc0, src=(string)src, time=(guint64)16000, ts=(guint64)6072172000;
0:00:06.072209000 40898    0x11d816920 TRACE             GST_TRACER :0:: element-latency, element-id=(string)0x11e850440, element=(string)capsfilter0, src=(string)src, time=(guint64)28000, ts=(guint64)6072200000;
0:00:06.072224000 40898    0x11d816920 TRACE             GST_TRACER :0:: element-latency, element-id=(string)0x11e824660, element=(string)videoconvert0, src=(string)src, time=(guint64)17000, ts=(guint64)6072217000;
0:00:06.072468000 40898    0x11d816920 TRACE             GST_TRACER :0:: element-latency, element-id=(string)0x11e83f280, element=(string)autovideosink0, src=(string)src, time=(guint64)21594000, ts=(guint64)6072456000;
....
```

So here you have a starting point to analyze latency (`time=(guint64)...` values) per element and experiment with different settings

More details in this article https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/tracing.html?gi-language=c#use-cases

Comment: I followed your exact commands but for some reason my .log file remains empty even after I close gstreamer (Ctrl+C). I saw it working and producing output normally. Any idea as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: @Anton9988 can you confirm that it produce some output without `GST_DEBUG_FILE=./latency.log` ?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, the issue was that I was running it on Yocto Linux and Yocto requires specific parameters to be enabled in order to allow GST Tracing. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: actually it seems it's still not working. I was wondering what's the best way to check if GST_TRACERS are enabled on system? Would it be through `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep tracers`?

Comment: I ran into the same issue as @Anton9988 I was able to get this to work by rebuilding `gstreamer` using `meson` with the extra parameter `-Dgstreamer:coretracers=enabled`